# no-eclipse tomcat env variable equivalent

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I can set an environment variable with Eclipse when I click on the Tomcat Server and then  `Open Launch configuration -> Environment -> Variable, Value`. What is no-gui, no-eclipse textual-xml equivalent of this variable setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Context Parameters

See: [*Context Parameters*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters) section of [The Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html) page.

> You can configure named values that will be made visible to the web application as servlet context initialization parameters by nesting `<Parameter>` elements inside this element. For example, you can create an initialization parameter like this:

```
<Context ...>
  ...
  <Parameter name="companyName" value="My Company, Incorporated"
         override="false"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

> This is equivalent to the inclusion of the following element in the web application deployment descriptor (/WEB-INF/web.xml):

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>companyName</param-name>
  <param-value>My Company, Incorporated</param-value>
</context-param>
```

> but does not require modification of the deployment descriptor to customize this value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gnu-linux operating system you can edit the **catalina.sh** script to export you environment variable. First line of the script (after comments, of course) should be

```
export variableName=variableValue
```

The credit is for Lucas that told me how to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant arguments passed to the launching of your servlet context, see the [Answer by miku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4588382/642706).

## Environment Entries

If you meant the [*Environment Entries*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Environment_Entries) feature, use `<Environment>` rather than `<Parameter>` seen in that other Answer.

Here is an example where I set a flag signaling if I am running the web app for [development, testing, acceptance, education, or production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development%2C_testing%2C_acceptance_and_production).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Domain: DEV, TEST, ACPT, ED, PROD  -->
    <Environment name = "work.basil.example.deployment-mode"
                 description = "Signals whether to run this web-app with development, testing, acceptance, education, or production settings."
                 value = "DEV"
                 type = "java.lang.String"
                 override = "false"
                 />
</Context>
```

You have your choice of a few places to place such XML. For this example, we would want to externalize the file, keeping it outside the [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) file containing our web-app. By externalizing, we can deploy our WAR to any of the dev, test, acpt, ed, or prod servers without needing special builds or manual editing. So for this purpose I like to use the feature of Tomcat allowing for an XML file named the same as the context. The file is place in the `conf` folder, in which you create nested folders named after the Tomcat engine and the host. For example, on my development machine that would be `my_tomcat_base_folder/conf/Catalina/localhost/example.xml` where `example` is the name of my context, `Catalina` is the engine name, and `localhost` is the host name (not using a domain name while in development).

The syntax of the above XML is Tomcat-specific. For use in Servlet-standard places, such as the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file, the equivalent as documented in the Servlet 4 spec section 14.4.21 would be:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>work.basil.example.deployment-mode</env-entry-name>
    <description>Signals whether to run this web-app with development, testing, acceptance, education, or production settings.</description>
    <env-entry-value>DEV</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```